# Line chart using d3 charts

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I am able to generate a Line chart using d3 charts with the code below

```
function renderChart() {

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("line.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Y - Axis");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });


});

}


Line.csv

date,temparature
20111001,124
20111002,58
20111003,49
20111004,100
```

This code works only if the input format is date,temparature

How do I make it work for the format below (Place, temparature)?

```
Line.csv

place,temparature
India,124
Us,58
Uk,49
China,100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just change this:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
```

to this:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range([0, width]);
```

Then search and replace all occurrences of "date" with "place" and remove the `parseDate` stuff and you should be good.

Comment: It works fine now. How do I get the intersection point on the chart?

Comment: Do you mean the point where the line would touch the Y axis?  With an ordinal X scale usually the line begins at the first value, not intersecting with the Y axis because that intersection point doesn't have any meaning in terms of the data.

Comment: No, I was asking about the intersection points on the line itself

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but scaling the data using the X and Y scale will produce the location of each point.

Comment: I mean, I just got the line with the code above, I dint get any location points on the line.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The `d3.svg.line` generator only draws a line.  If you want any other datapoint representations you have to add them separately.  You can add a small circle element at each point (or whatever shape you want).

Comment: After the changes, I am getting an extra line on the chart if I send numbers in the first column!

Comment: You need 2 steps. First, draw the line with exactly the data you used before (when your line looked right).  Second, create <circle> elements using exactly the same data/scales.

Comment: how do i get rid of the 2nd line that am getting when I send numbers in the first column?

Comment: You'll have to post a running example for further help because I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40044/d3-charts .Can you come here so that I can xplain about my prob in detail

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6J9J4/1/ .Here is the link for the fiddle. I donno where am going wrong. Please do help me in solving this

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8WXck/10/.  You were using an ordinal scale but were not including all discrete values from your data domain.  You were setting `range` with only 2 values and then using `d3.extent` to get the [min, max].  What you need with an ordinal scale is to set the domain to all discrete values from the data (e.g. ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) and then configure the range using `rangePoints` or `rangeBands`.  I chose `rangePoints because the line vertices act as points.  You can play around with the padding, I just used 1 as an example.

Comment: Thanx a lot Scott. That really helped a lot :)

Answer (score -2):

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    if (this._listenToEvents) {
        // Reset inmediatelly  
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")

        //List item
        path.each(function() {
            this._listenToEvents = false;
        });
    }

    d3.selectAll("#" + id + " svg").remove();

    if (level == 1) {
        TransformChartData(chartData, options, 0, d[xVarName]);
        BuildBar(id, chartData, options, 0);
    } else {
        var nonSortedChart = chartData.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(b[options[0].yaxis]) - parseFloat(a[options[0].yaxis]);
        });
        TransformChartData(nonSortedChart, options, 1, d[xVarName]);
        BuildBar(id, nonSortedChart, options, 1);
    }
});
```